# Using GET to return data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, get, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to connect to MongoDB with Web Api, trying to return the connected data in MongoDB using Get. The name of the database is "test" and the collection name is "restaurant".

Here is the code I have

```
      public IEnumerable<restaurants> Get()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var dbs = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = dbs.GetCollection<restaurants>("restaurants");


        return collection;
     }
```

The last collection word is underlined, and I have not found what needs to be returned (in place of collection) in order to show the database in MongoDB (using postman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to return IMongoCollection, not  IEnumerable so last line is underlined :)

Try to transform collection to List (asynchronously), then return. For example:

```
public Task<List<restaurants>> GetRestaurantsAsync()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var dbs = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = dbs.GetCollection<restaurants>("restaurants");


    return await collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
 }


 public async Task MainAsync()
 {
    List<restaurants> restaurantsList = await GetRestaurantsAsync();
 }
```

Note: it depends on which version of mongo c# driver you're using.

Comment: I had to use 

public async Task MainAsync()
        {
}
method to use the await, and I do not know how to return the list back as an array, seems that Task cannot return anything.

Comment: I edited my answer, according to your comment. Hope it's more understandable.